# Is there a fingerprint reader tool available for Ubuntu?

Tags: security, fingerprint-reader

I've got a fingerprint reader (Authentek AES2810) built in to my laptop (Dell Latitude E5500) and would like to take a picture of my fingerprint (not just to use it to log-in or something alike, but to take a viewable picture). Is there an application for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe fprint [fprint demo](http://www.reactivated.net/fprint/wiki/Fprint_demo)

is the right app for you. But I don't know if you can open the saved pics with an image viewer but you can see it right after taking the pic.

Answer (score 2):

I know that fingerprint-gui stores the fingerprint data locally in .bir files. I'm not sure if there's any way to open those in some sort of image viewer, but that's the only solution I can think of.